# Getting fatal error: 'features.h' file not found #include <features.h> while trying to generate .so files for pjsip android

Tags: android, pjsip, csip-simple

I am using [CSipSimple](https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple) library for VoIP calling feature in my android app and recently my app was rejected on play store because the OpenSSL version with these libs was old. I need to update the .so PJSIP files according to the new/supported OpenSSL version.

I am trying to generate .so files based on OpenSSL (version :openssl-1.1.1-pre6) for armeabi-v7, armeabi-v8a, armeabix86, and armeabi. I am using these as references:
1. https://medium.com/@shehrazjazib/pjsip-build-for-android-with-integration-of-g729-codec-7d677ea68373
2. https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#OpenSSLSupport

I am able to generate the toolchain and run configure-android script. Also able to execute make dep successfully. But I am getting error while executing **make** like so:

```
In file included from ../src/pjmedia-codec/openh264.cpp:19:
In file included from ../include/pjmedia-codec/openh264.h:22:
In file included from ../include/pjmedia-codec/types.h:28:
In file included from ../include/pjmedia-codec/config.h:35:
In file included from ../include/pjmedia/types.h:28:
In file included from ../include/pjmedia/config.h:27:
In file included from ../../pjlib/include/pj/config.h:313:
In file included from ../../pjlib/include/pj/compat/size_t.h:28:
In file included from /mnt/e/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r17-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r17/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stddef.h:40:
/mnt/e/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r17-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r17/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__config:169:10: fatal error:
      'features.h' file not found
#include <features.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/mnt/e/PJSIP/pjproject-2.7.2/build/rules.mak:173: recipe for target 'output/pjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/openh264.o' failed
make[2]: *** [output/pjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/openh264.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/e/PJSIPOpenSSL/pjproject-2.7.2/pjmedia/build'
Makefile:220: recipe for target 'libpjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a' failed
make[1]: *** [libpjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/e/PJSIPOpenSSL/pjproject-2.7.2/pjmedia/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am new to native android so I know very little of it. I am able to insert features.h from /usr/include folder but that in turn gets error for other missing header files.

Please can anyone help me with this error? I need to be able to generate .so files for PJSIP android.

*Please note: I am using a Ubuntu bash on my windows 10 OS.*

**EDIT**

I am now trying to work with ubuntu OS in a virtual box and while trying to generate PjSip files using OpenSSL I get this linker error:

```
make depend && make _all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rspl/Downloads/openssl-1.1.0h'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rspl/Downloads/openssl-1.1.0h'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rspl/Downloads/openssl-1.1.0h'
CC="/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Iusr/include --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm" /usr/bin/perl crypto/aes/asm/aes-armv4.pl void crypto/aes/aes-armv4.S
( trap "rm -f crypto/aes/aes-armv4.o.*" INT 0; \
      /home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Iusr/include --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -E  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -Icrypto -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE crypto/aes/aes-armv4.S | \
      /usr/bin/perl -ne '/^#(line)?\s*[0-9]+/ or print' > crypto/aes/aes-armv4.o.s && \
      /home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Iusr/include --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -c -o crypto/aes/aes-armv4.o crypto/aes/aes-armv4.o.s )
/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Iusr/include --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cbc.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o crypto/aes/aes_cbc.c
/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Iusr/include --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cfb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.c
/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Iusr/include --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -mandroid -fPIC --sysroot=/home/rspl/Downloads/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -Wa,--noexecstack  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_ecb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_ecb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_ecb.o crypto/aes/aes_ecb.c
crypto/aes/aes_ecb.c:10:20: fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory
 #include <assert.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [crypto/aes/aes_ecb.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rspl/Downloads/openssl-1.1.0h'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Since gcc is unable to find header file in crypto/include, I explicitly added -Iusr/include in CFLAGS for still getting the same error.

Comment: Bring your console output in the description and wrap it with code highlighter.

Answer (score 0):

because some methods/files has been deprecated or removed from NDK on hign level version.

try to add : 
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang or NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 in the begining of configure comment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I didn't quite get you

Comment: in your case try: NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9

Comment: my whole comment is: NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags

Comment: try use NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang, and please attach your comment